# Volitional + と without follow-up

Tags: particle-と, volitional-form

The following sentence was part of the last exercise I did:

> あなたが何を見つけようと、それは途方もなく危険なもの_____。大勢の人間が私達を殺そうとしてるんだから。
>   A
>
> A. に間違いない、B. に越したことはない、C. に相違ない、D. に決まっている

The right answer was D.

The thing is, I have trouble understanding the meaning of this sentence.
I think I understand most of it though:

> 大勢の人間が私達を殺そうとしてるんだから。
>
> That's because a lot of people are trying to kill us.
>
> それは途方もなく危険なもの
>
> This (is?) something incredibly dangerous

Then I'm a bit stuck.
I feel like the key to understanding this sentence is that "あなたが何を見つけようと、" without any follow-up.
I think I remember learning something like the "思う" or "する" that usually comes after the volitional form + と can be omitted.
However, I cannot wrap my head around this part.

How should I parse this sentence?
And what's the meaning of it once "に決まっている" has been inserted?

Comment: https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8-you-gayou-to/ Maybe this website will help you translate it yourself. It is always better to try to understand it by yourself

Comment: The exercise question seems kind of defective even I think I get the surface meaning. I have no idea what "途方もなく危険なもの" is in that context so I can't decide what modality I should use. Aside from the textbook grammar (I presume), I don't think D is the only answer whenever you see that sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel this is a difficult question even to some native speakers... The meaning of the first sentence is "No matter what you are going to find (e.g., in this dungeon), it **must be** something incredibly dangerous." For this ようと, see: [What are the grammar rules behind this clause, 「才能があろうがなかろうが」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48292/5010) and [Meaning of volitional passive form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32949/5010)

So, you are supposed to choose the correct expression that corresponds to this "must be". B ("nothing is better than a dangerous thing") is clearly wrong. A and C are close, but these are usually used in the context where you are identifying something/someone with a concrete evidence. ～に決まっている (or ～に違いない, without 間) expresses a strong suspicion, which is better in this context because the speaker knows almost nothing about what they are going to find.

> 太郎に間違いない。 = 太郎に相違ない。
>     [seeing a photograph / collating a fingerprint] It must be Taro.
>
> 太郎に違いない。 = 太郎に決まっている。
>     ["Who ate the cake?"] It must be Taro.

Comment: Ah, so 何を見つけようと simply means 何を見つけても?

Comment: @Rightleg Yes, that's correct!